# Xcode is running really slow

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, performance

I've recently tried to use Xcode 8 to make iOS apps and to test things in Swift however it is impossible to work on as doing a simple 'print("Hello World")' takes easily over a minute to process to print it to the console, I tried doing regular development as well by creating UI buttons etc. but when I try to compile it, it is too slow to work and that is with simple things. My computer is the Mid 2012 Macbook Pro Non-retina with 4GB of RAM, not a quick computer but I can program in Python without these problems. If anyone knows some solutions please tell me! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: *"My computer is the Mid 2012 Macbook Pro Non-retina with 4GB of RAM..."* Oof. I bet it has a spinning disk instead of an SSD, too.

Comment: @TomHarrington Yep...

Comment: That's your biggest problem then. With 4GB of RAM, Xcode is going to swap to disk a lot. With a spinning disk, swapping will be slow. If you can upgrade to an SSD and/or add RAM, that will help, otherwise you're kind of stuck.

Comment: @TomHarrington I am planning on buying an SSD or RAM however I live in South Africa and there is no MacBook compatible RAM I can find here and can't find one on Amazon that ships here and SSD's are really expensive here! Thanks for the help

Comment: FWIW, Macs have used standard RAM for a very long time. Look up the spec for your Mac and find RAM that meets that spec. It's the same as on any PC, just a matter of being the right size and speed.

Comment: @TomHarrington Yea been looking around but only ones I could find are ones that are not correct size and are not dimensions required.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you build a project for the **first time** do it normally (it will take a while like you described)

After the first build Go to *Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme*. Select *Build* in left side column and uncheck *Find implicit dependencies*.

This appears to be a well known problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62737

> "If there's not enough context to decide, the compiler has to go with the conservative choice and record it as cascading."

Comment: After doing this  nothing happened for me instead next day got linker command error and wasted for me around 2 hours to find error as I know nothing error in my code and later all struggles  found solution doing "undo" this process ( Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.)  gone my error now .

Answer (score 6):

Same issue for me. I had execute these instructions two times before the app would launch without hanging for a minute.

1. Unpair your phone from xcode
2. Launch xcode with your phone *not* plugged in
3. Plug your phone in
4. In xcode, under devices, unpair your phone
5. Stop xcode
6. Run the following commands

- `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport`
- `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ Device\ Logs`
- `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

7. Start xcode
8. Plug phone in

Comment: Hi Priyanka! I recommend you look at Stack Overflow's Markdown formatting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help It will make your questions/answers much easier to read (and thus understand)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window/Devices and Simulators/uncheck Connect Via Network