# Flutter run takes too long

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I'm trying to run Flutter in debug mode.

The "Running Xcode Build" takes 30 minutes.

Flutter doctor looks normal.

These are my dependencies:

```
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.19.2
  cloud_firestore: ^3.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.4.2
```

Did I configure something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caused by the Firestore Package. Took 1,5 hours to build. When following this step of Firebase it reduced the build times to 10 minutes

```
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Firebase Firestore, pls check the doc from

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

> Optional: Improve iOS & macOS build times by including the
> pre-compiled framework. Currently, the Firestore SDK for iOS depends
> on code that can take upwards of 5 minutes to build in Xcode. To
> reduce build times significantly, you can use a pre-compiled version
> by adding this line to the target 'Runner' do block in your Podfile:

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, this happened to me while building on a Tablet it took 25 minutes.

When I then switched to building on my iPhone it took about 8 minutes. So, there's nothing wrong with your Mac.

See also [Xcode is running really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166963/xcode-is-running-really-slow):

> When you build a project for the first time do it normally (it will
> take a while like you described)
>
> After the first build Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme. Select
> Build in left side column and uncheck Find implicit dependencies.
>
> This appears to be a well known problem:
> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62737